Caused by: org.messaging.handler.annotation.support.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Could not resolve method parameter at index 1 in public void
I'm developing Kafka Consumer App and getting below error when manually trying acknowledge and confirm. What might be causing the issue?
Error details:
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: invokeHandler Failed
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2976) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2921) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2888) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.lambda$doInvokeRecordListener$57(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2805) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.lambda$observe$4(Observation.java:544) ~[micrometer-observation-1.11.11.jar:1.11.11]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observeWithContext(Observation.java:603) ~[micrometer-observation-1.11.11.jar:1.11.11]
    at io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:544) ~[micrometer-observation-1.11.11.jar:1.11.11]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2803) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2655) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2541) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2179) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1519) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1483) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1357) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Restored Stack Trace
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.checkAckArg(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:397) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:383) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:92) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2907) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Acknowledgment available as an argument, the listener container must have a MANUAL AckMode to populate the Acknowledgment.
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.checkAckArg(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:397) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:383) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:92) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:53) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2907) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Could not resolve method parameter at index 1 in public void com.learnkafka.consumer.LibraryEventsConsumerManualOffset.onMessage(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String>,org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment): 1 error(s): [Error in object 'acknowledgment': codes []; arguments []; default message [Payload value must not be empty]] 
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.PayloadMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(PayloadMethodArgumentResolver.java:128) ~[spring-messaging-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaNullAwarePayloadArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(KafkaNullAwarePayloadArgumentResolver.java:46) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:118) ~[spring-messaging-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:147) ~[spring-messaging-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:115) ~[spring-messaging-6.0.19.jar:6.0.19]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:56) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:375) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.16.jar:3.0.16]
    ... 17 common frames omitted

LibraryEventsConsumerManualOffset.java
@Component
@Slf4j
public class LibraryEventsConsumerManualOffset implements AcknowledgingMessageListener<Integer,String> {

    @Override
    @KafkaListener(topics = {"library-events"}, containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> consumerRecord, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        log.info("ConsumerRecord : {}", consumerRecord);
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }
}

LibraryEventsConsumerConfig.java
@AutoConfiguration
@EnableKafka
public class LibraryEventsConsumerConfig {

    private final KafkaProperties properties;

    public LibraryEventsConsumerConfig(KafkaProperties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ObjectProvider<ConsumerFactory<Object, Object>> kafkaConsumerFactory,
            ObjectProvider<ContainerCustomizer<Object, Object, ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Object, Object>>> kafkaContainerCustomizer) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory
                .getIfAvailable(() -> new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(this.properties.buildConsumerProperties())));
        //factory.setConcurrency(3);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
        return factory;
    }
}

pom.xml
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


For the configuration you show there is no need in the LibraryEventsConsumerConfig. Just follow plain application.properties:
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode=manual

And Spring Boot auto-configuration will do the stuff for you!

Thanks helpful. but would be always nice to play to learn more about the technology.
